# Undoing "always display images from a particular sender" in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I'm trying to undo the "always display images from a particular sender" option.
on the support page it's written:

> - Sign in to Gmail.
> - Open the message.
> - Click show details at the top of the message pane.
> - Click Don't display from now on."

The problem is that the "Don't display from now on" DOES NOT appear when clicking the "Show details". What else can be done?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?